# Is regularization in Keras equivalent to a standard Ridge or Lasso problem?

Tags: neural-networks, lasso, regularization, keras

With the python package `Keras`, you can use $\ell_2$ or $\ell_1$ regularization but you have to use the option on each layer. But I definitely cannot tell if using it layer after layer is equivalent to this minimization problem (for example with $\ell_1$/LASSO):
$$
\min_{\boldsymbol{\omega}} \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} (y_i - f_{\boldsymbol{\omega}}(\boldsymbol{x}_i))^2 + \lambda \sum^{d}_{j=1} |\omega_j|
$$

I think the equivalence is not trivial, even though back-propagation should intuitively lead to it.

Comment: What does the set $j = 1, 2, 3, \dots, d$ denote and how is it related to the neural network or lasso problem? This specificity is important, because in Keras you have the flexibility to only apply L1/L2/both to some but not all layers, whereas Lasso generally applies regularization to all regression parameters *except* the intercept.

Comment: Correct, i should have added that the $j$ indices correspond to all the weights in the network (excluding biases).  The function $f_{\boldsymbol{\omega}}(\cdot)$ is a neural network function ; and we're minimizing the MSE with a LASSO penalization (using some gradient descent algorithm).